# Getting an empty list while parsing HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've recently faced a problem with parsing the website. I need to get the piece of text from this HTML:

```html
<span content="Москва, СВАО, р-н Ярославский, м. Ростокино, улица Проходчиков, 8" itemprop="name"></span>
```

I wanted to get text after `<span content=...>`.

```py
for a in self.find_all("span", {"itemprop": "name"}):
    a = a.text.split(',')
    print(a[2])
```

But I get an empty list.

Comment: Can you post the URL?

Comment: Perhaps `.get_text` will be of use.

Comment: @Arn, i still get this)

```<bound method Tag.get_text of <span content="Москва, ВАО, р-н Перово, м. Шоссе Энтузиастов, улица Плеханова, 35" itemprop="name"></span>>```

Comment: @NicolasGervais, yes sure
https://www.cian.ru/kupit-1-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/

Comment: Can you post your expected output as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking after content value.use **CSS** selector and **content** attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response=requests.get("https://www.cian.ru/kupit-1-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select('span[itemprop="name"][content]'):
    print(item['content'])
```

**Output**:

```
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, Люберецкие Поля мкр, 13-й кв-л, к16
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, улица Лавриненко, 5
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, Люберецкие Поля мкр, 12-й кв-л, Квартал Некрасовка ЖК, к9
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, улица Маресьева
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Мичуринский проспект, улица Лобачевского, 118к2
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Филевский парк, м. Шелепиха, Береговой ЖК, к1
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, Люберецкие Поля мкр, 13-й кв-л, к16
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, Люберецкие Поля мкр, 13-й кв-л, к16
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Филевский парк, м. Фили, Багратионовский проезд
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Раменки, Мичуринский проспект
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Мичуринский проспект, улица Лобачевского, 120
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Раменки, улица Лобачевского, 118к1
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Крылатское, м. Крылатское, Рублевское шоссе, 70к2
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Крылатское, м. Крылатское, Рублевское шоссе, 70к6
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Раменки, улица Лобачевского, 118к2
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Аминьевское шоссе, улица Лобачевского, 114
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Филевский парк, м. Фили, Багратионовский проезд
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, улица Вертолетчиков, 13
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, улица Вертолетчиков, 13
Москва, ЦАО, р-н Басманный, м. Электрозаводская, улица Госпитальный Вал, 5С7
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Раменки, Мичуринский проспект
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, Люберецкие Поля мкр, 12-й кв-л, Квартал Некрасовка ЖК, к9
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Раменки, м. Мичуринский проспект, улица Лобачевского, 120
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Филевский парк, м. Фили, Багратионовский проезд
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, улица Лавриненко, 5
Москва, ЮВАО, р-н Некрасовка, м. Некрасовка, улица Лавриненко, 5
Москва, ЗАО, р-н Филевский парк, м. Шелепиха, Береговой ЖК, к1
Москва, СЗАО, р-н Хорошево-Мневники, м. Хорошево, 3-я Хорошевская улица, 19А
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve content from span in the following manner:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.cian.ru/kupit-1-komnatnuyu-kvartiru/'
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
found_class_with_content = 'c6e8ba5398--address-links--1tfGW'
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_=found_class_with_content)
for div in divs:
    content = div.find('span', {"itemprop": "name"})['content']
    print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this peace of code help you:

```
a.contents[0]
```

or

```
a.content
```